# Print HTML tabindex number is odd and even method

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

Hello i just wanted to print tabindex like this,
1,2,3,4,5,6,7.

[image]

so first its should come 1 then 2 then 3 then 4...

here is the link of code if you want to check,

```
<div className="App">
  {[1, 2, 3, 4, 5].map((i, key) => (
    <div>
      <h1> tabIndex = {i} Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2> tabIndex = {i + 2} Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <br />
    </div>
  ))}
</div>
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-wescoff-04nlp

Comment: why don't have numbers as `[1,3,5,7,...]`